# Piping config file to genkernel

Tags: kernel, pipe, gentoo

I'm a gentoo user and I've become I a bit tired of copying my kernel config file when a new kernel comes out. I wonder if it's possible to pipe the configuration file to genkernel directly. Something like this:

```
sudo genkernel --install --clean --kernel-config=$(gunzip/proc/config.gz) --menuconfig all
```

or this:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | sudo genkernel --install --clean --kernel-config=- --menuconfig all
```

But I can't get it to work since I'm not really that good at piping/shell scripting. Any ideas?

EDIT: with `$(gunzip /proc/config.gz)` it says `gzip: /proc/config: No such file or directory`. But it's untrue since `zcat /proc/config.gz` prints all my settings

Answer (score 0):

Your shell invocation is wrong.

`$(gunzip /proc/config.gz)` -> this tries to /proc/config.gz to /proc/config. Nothing is sent to stdout, but stderr does get triggered in this case, because it's not permitted to make new files in `/proc` (that's the `no such file or directory error`).

You have to tell `genkernel` to read a file descriptor (it doesn't support `-` as a shortcut for stdin) for the config, so you have two options:

1. Pipes:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | sudo genkernel --install \
--clean --kernel-config=/dev/stdin --menuconfig all
```

2. Process substitution:

```
sudo genkernel --install --clean \
--kernel-config=<(zcat /proc/config.gz) --menuconfig all
```

I'd suggest the latter, but would also like to point out that by default, genkernel saves every kernel config to `/etc/kernels/`, and you can source them from there:

```
sudo genkernel --install --clean \
--kernel-config=/etc/kernels/kernel-config-$(uname -m)-$(uname -r) \
--menuconfig all
```

(beware if you change config options and rebuild the same kernel, it overwrites the previous file in that directory, by design).